# How can I have a script in Blogspot template that uses the Blogspot variables?

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

I have the following Facebook iframe as part of the template:

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=100&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:576px; height:24px;'/>
```

The main feature is that it uses the Blogspot variable `data:post.url` as the link that the user can "Like". Unfortunately recently blogspot decided to redirect people to their local blospot addresses, so if you open `example.blogspot.com` in the UK, you will be redirected to `example.blogspot.co.uk`, and you can't see any likes of people from outside of the island.

The obvious fix is to make everyone like the main .com page, so I created a script to generate this iframe dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<iframe allowTransparency='true' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=");
var thisUrl = "data:post.url";
var beginning = thisUrl.indexOf("blogspot")+9;
var end = thisUrl.indexOf("/", 15);
document.write(thisUrl.substring(0, beginning));
document.write("com");//change regional url to com
document.write(thisUrl.substring(end));
document.write("&layout=standard&show_faces=false&width=100&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:576px; height:24px;'></iframe>");
</script>
```

To make Blogspot accept it I had to html-ecape bits of it, but I can't get the variable `data:post.url` substituted to a correct value - it stays literally what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show Blogger variables you need to use `<data:blog.varName/>`.

So, in your case, instead of:

```
var thisUrl = "data:post.url";
```

You need to use:

```
var thisUrl = "<data:post.url/>";
```

UPD 1: if you want to use page url in head section, use `<data:blog.url/>` not `<data:post.url/>`.

UPD 2: but why you don't use `window.location`?

Comment: Re 2: Because I want it to work for the main blog page as well (which lists a few latest blog entries).

Answer (score 3):

Grzenio.

This does not directly answer your question but you can use

Replace `data:post.url` with `data:post.canonicalUrl`

This will mean that all your likes etc will use the .com version of your blog.

So you should not need to use any javascript etc.