# Facebook comments count to blogger

Tags: jquery, facebook, blogger

I want to embed an accountant reviews in the home of my blog. Got a jquery code to get the number of comments is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
$(function(){
    var myurl = 'http://graph.facebook.com/';
    var post = 'URL POST'
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl + post,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#div1").html(data.comments);
       }
    });

});
}//]]>  
</script>
  <div id="div1"></div>
```

I was unable to get the post url in "var post", I tried all of the following:

- var post = expr:href='data:post.url';
- var post = <;data:post.url/>;
- var post = "data:post.url"

Someone could help me, please?

I know I can use: `<span class='fb-comments-count' expr:data-href='data:post.canonicalUrl'/>`

But using graph takes less time to charge.

Comment: If you just want to send the URL of the current page you’re on – `window.location.href`

Comment: In this case will the url of the post, as this counter is alone in the home of the blog, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @lualescalante a similar question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001586/how-can-i-have-a-script-in-blogspot-template-that-uses-the-blogspot-variables